# Layouts that give more horizontal space for equations

Tags: margins, document-classes, geometry, layout

This is a typography question as well as a LaTeX question.

I'm writing a document where some of the equations are very wide, and I'm looking for ways to lay out the document that will help me fit as many of the equations on single lines as possible, i.e. to minimise the use of `\multline` and other ways of splitting long equations up.

An obvious solution would be to reduce the margins using the `geometry' package, but I know that that sort of thing has an effect on readability, so one shouldn't mess with it unless one knows what one is doing, which I don't. So I'm wondering if there is any existing solution to laying out documents that meets these requirements:

- more horizontal space for equations than the default `\documentclass{article}` offers
- maintains the same level of readability for the text
- is within the norms for the layout of a scientific paper / preprint.

Specifically, the question is: **where can I find good, well tested examples, designed by people who know more about typography than me, of page layouts that meet these requirements?** I'm not asking how to adjust the page layout by myself - I know how to do that but don't feel I know enough about typography to make the right choices.

Here is an MWE to try and demonstrate what I mean. The goal is for an equation of about this size to fit comfortably on the page without spilling into the right margin, **without** modifying the equation to split it across multiple lines, and without hurting readability of the text by making the lines too wide. There is some leeway about the exact size of the equation - I don't mind splitting some of them. It might be that my requirements are impossible altogether, but I figured it can't hurt to ask.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

Here is an equation with some snazzy tikz diagrams in it:
\begin{equation}
    \raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}} = 
    \raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}.
\end{equation}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(My equations are wide because they contain tikz diagrams, not because they're horrible sprawling math expressions.)

Instead of decreasing the margins, an alternative might be to let the equation spill into the left margin as well as the right, so that at least it's centred on the page, even if it's wider than the text. I'm open to alternative suggestions along those lines also. The main goal is for it to look good (and look like a scientific paper) while also allowing the equations to fit on single lines.

Comment: Please provide an example what you after. So far your question is to general and can't be as such answered. Layout of page you cab setup by use of the `geometry` package, equations can be written in more lines by use environments defined in the `amsmath/mathtools` packages.

Comment: @Zarko does the edit help? It is a question about where to find already tested layouts, designed by people who know more about typography than me. I'm not asking how to adjust the layout myself. I know how to do that, but don't don't feel I know enough to make the right typographical choices. I also know how to put equations across more than one line, but the whole point of the question is that I want to make the text width wider in order to avoid doing so, without hurting readability.

Comment: @Zarko I've added an MWE for good measure.

Comment: Will such a document ever be included in a printed, bound volume?  If it is, there will be rigid requirements based on the size of the printed page and the clearance from the outside edge (where something very wide could be physically cut off) and from the spine, where it could either be cut off or become impossible to read without breaking the back of the volume to flatten it out.  You might consider the possibility of reorganizing your material so that the wide elements can be oriented landscape.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that's a good point. But currently I'm only aiming to put this document on the arXiv preprint server, so it's destined only for screens and consumer printers. If it would be reworked for publication and accepted there would usually be a style file from the publisher, so I'd have to reformat things anyway.

Comment: If it's not too much wider than the text block, it would be better to have it hang over both edges equally.  The `mathtools` package has a command `\mathclap{...}` that will make it look like it has zero width, split at the horizontal center.  That's fine as long as there's no equation number; with an equation number, that will overprint.  I know this has been asked before, so now I'll try to look for the earlier question.

Comment: Not having found the answer I'm sure is there, here is a suggestion.  Determine how much wider the equation is than the text (perhaps setting it and looking at the overfull message).  Divide that amount in half, and insert `\hspace{-<dimen>}` on each side.  That should allow the equation to "fit", centered, allowing the `equation` mechanism to add an equation number on a separate line,